# How can I get rid of `Loading /home/user/.emacs.d/package.el (source)...done` message after installing a package manually?

Tags: init-file

I'm trying to install this [package](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-bullets/blob/master/org-bullets.el) manually, adding the `org-bullets.el` file to my emacs directory.

As suggested, I enabled it adding

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/org-bullets.el")

(require 'org-bullets)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-bullets-mode)
```

to my `init.el`

The program works but now when I start Emacs the mini buffer always shows this message:

`Loading /home/user/.emacs.d/org-bullets.el (source)...done`

How can I get rid of it?

I'm running Emacs 27.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crib the `load-file` function and replace it with a silent version.

The `load-file` function looks like this (just do `C-h f load-file` and then click on the link of the file that contains it (`files.el`) to see the definition of the function):

```el
(defun load-file (file)
  "Load the Lisp file named FILE."
  ;; This is a case where .elc and .so/.dll make a lot of sense.
  (interactive (list (let ((completion-ignored-extensions
                            (remove module-file-suffix
                                    (remove ".elc"
                                            completion-ignored-extensions))))
               (read-file-name "Load file: " nil nil 'lambda))))
  (load (expand-file-name file) nil nil t))
```

As you can see, it calls `load`. If you examine the doc string of `load` it says:

> (load FILE &optional NOERROR NOMESSAGE NOSUFFIX MUST-SUFFIX)
>
> ...
>
> Print messages at start and end of loading unless
> optional third arg NOMESSAGE is non-nil (but ‘force-load-messages’
> overrides that).

`force-load-messages` is `nil` by default (but check your configuration with `C-h v force-load-messages` to make sure). Assuming that's the case, all you need to do is define your own `load-file` function early in your init file (before you use it to load `org-bullets`), but when your function calls `load`, change it so that the `nomessage` parameter is `t` instead of `nil`:

```el
(defun load-file (file)
  "Load the Lisp file named FILE."
  ;; This is a case where .elc and .so/.dll make a lot of sense.
  (interactive (list (let ((completion-ignored-extensions
                            (remove module-file-suffix
                                    (remove ".elc"
                                            completion-ignored-extensions))))
               (read-file-name "Load file: " nil nil 'lambda))))
  (load (expand-file-name file) nil t t))
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The message now is gone.